# Error using corpus widget in Orange v 3.25.0 text mining and no import document option?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, orange, corpus

I am experimenting with Orange data mining tool. When I use the 'Corpus' widget from the text mining section it gives me the error:

Corpus widget error:

[image]

I have tried many things, but am still unable to resolve this issue.

Besides that, in text mining, it does not show import document option in orange v 3.25. I just want to know the options to import text files into the Orange.

Comment: Seems that your document is not properly loaded or is empty from the start. "None type" means that no "data" arrived...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the error comes when I click on 'Corpus', so the error does not let me choose/load any file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your Text version is outdated. Please update Text add-on. For issues with Orange, please always head over to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text/issues) and see if your issue already exists. If not, open a new issue.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Let me try it again.